# ag-grid row groups are repeating

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using ag-grid-react in my react project. I need a table with row-grouping functionality, so from the official [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/) this is what i did.

```
const GRID_OPTIONS = {
  defaultColDef: {
    resizable: true,
    suppressMovable: true
    // suppressMenu: true
    // unSortIcon: true
  },
  frameworkComponents: {
    statusBar: StatusBar,
    customEditor: CellEditor,
    booleanFilter: BooleanFilter,
    customRenderer: CellRenderer,
    dateFilter: customDateFilter
  },
  suppressContextMenu: true,
  autoHeight: true,
  rowSelection: "multiple",
  rowDeselection: true,
  rowModelType: "serverSide",
  cacheBlockSize: AppConstants.PAGE_SIZE,
  paginationPageSize: AppConstants.PAGE_SIZE,
  getRowNodeId: data => data.id,
  overlayNoRowsTemplate: `<span style="padding: 10px; border: 2px solid #444; background: lightgoldenrodyellow;">
        No Data found
    </span>`
};

const columnDefs = [
  {
    "field": "_",
    "colId": "_",
    "hide": true,
    "lockVisible": true,
    "filter": "agTextColumnFilter",
    "filterParams": {
      "newRowsAction": "keep"
    }
  },
  {
    "field": "controlHeading",
    "colId": "controlHeading",
    "headerName": "Control Heading",
    "sortable": false,
    "suppressMenu": true,
    "rowGroup": true, // <== row group enabled here
    "hide": true
  },
  {
    "field": "siNo",
    "colId": "siNo",
    "headerName": "Si No",
    "sortable": true,
    "filter": "agNumberColumnFilter",
    "filterParams": {
      "clearButton": true
    },
    "pinned": ""
  },
  {
    "field": "control",
    "colId": "control",
    "headerName": "Control",
    "sortable": true,
    "filter": "agSetColumnFilter",
    "filterParams": {
      "newRowsAction": "keep",
      "clearButton": true,
      "selectAllOnMiniFilter": true,
      "syncValuesLikeExcel": true
    },
    "pinned": ""
  },
  {
    "field": "checkGroup",
    "colId": "checkGroup",
    "headerName": "Check Group",
    "sortable": true,
    "filter": "agSetColumnFilter",
    "filterParams": {
      "newRowsAction": "keep",
      "clearButton": true,
      "selectAllOnMiniFilter": true,
      "syncValuesLikeExcel": true
    },
    "pinned": ""
  }
]

...

        <div className="ag-theme-material gridSize">
          <AgGridReact
            reactNext={true}
            onCellValueChanged={onCellValueChanged}
            onGridReady={onGridReady}
            columnDefs={columnDefs}
            pagination={true}
            onSelectionChanged={onRowSelect}
            {...GRID_OPTIONS}
          ></AgGridReact>
        </div>
```

**API response:**

```
[
  {
    "id": "5f20fb0bbb4d0700013096c3",
    "cloudName": "AWS",
    "control": "Ensure CloudTrail is enabled in all regions (Scored)",
    "controlHeading": "Logging",
    "siNo": 2.1,
    "checkGroup": "CloudTrail Enabled",
    "yes": 2,
    "no": 1,
    "complianceStandard": "CIS AWS 1.2.0"
  },
  {
    "id": "5f20fb0bbb4d0700013096c4",
    "cloudName": "AWS",
    "control": "Ensure CloudTrail log file validation is enabled (Scored)",
    "controlHeading": "Logging",
    "siNo": 2.2,
    "checkGroup": "CloudTrail File Validation",
    "yes": 2,
    "no": 0,
    "complianceStandard": "CIS AWS 1.2.0"
  },
  {
    "id": "5f20fb0bbb4d0700013096c5",
    "cloudName": "AWS",
    "control": "Ensure the S3 bucket used to store CloudTrail logs is not publicly accessible (Scored)",
    "controlHeading": "Logging",
    "siNo": 2.3,
    "checkGroup": "CloudTrail Bucket Private",
    "yes": 2,
    "no": 0,
    "complianceStandard": "CIS AWS 1.2.0"
  },
  {
    "id": "5f20fb0bbb4d0700013096c6",
    "cloudName": "AWS",
    "control": "Ensure CloudTrail trails are integrated with CloudWatch Logs (Scored)",
    "controlHeading": "Logging",
    "siNo": 2.4,
    "checkGroup": "CloudTrail To CloudWatch",
    "yes": 2,
    "no": 0,
    "complianceStandard": "CIS AWS 1.2.0"
  },
  {
    "id": "5f20fb0bbb4d0700013096c7",
    "cloudName": "AWS",
    "control": "Ensure AWS Config is enabled in all regions (Scored)",
    "controlHeading": "Logging",
    "siNo": 2.5,
    "checkGroup": "Config Service Enabled",
    "yes": 2,
    "no": 1,
    "complianceStandard": "CIS AWS 1.2.0"
  },
  {
    "id": "5f20fb0bbb4d0700013096c8",
    "cloudName": "AWS",
    "control": "Ensure S3 bucket access logging is enabled on the CloudTrail S3 bucket (Scored)",
    "controlHeading": "Logging",
    "siNo": 2.6,
    "checkGroup": "CloudTrail Bucket Access Logging",
    "yes": 2,
    "no": 0,
    "complianceStandard": "CIS AWS 1.2.0"
  },
  {
    "id": "5f20fb0bbb4d0700013096c9",
    "cloudName": "AWS",
    "control": "Ensure CloudTrail logs are encrypted at rest using KMS CMKs (Scored)",
    "controlHeading": "Logging",
    "siNo": 2.7,
    "checkGroup": "CloudTrail Encryption",
    "yes": 2,
    "no": 0,
    "complianceStandard": "CIS AWS 1.2.0"
  },
  {
    "id": "5f20fb0bbb4d0700013096ca",
    "cloudName": "AWS",
    "control": "Ensure rotation for customer created CMKs is enabled (Scored)",
    "controlHeading": "Logging",
    "siNo": 2.8,
    "checkGroup": "KMS Key Rotation",
    "yes": 2,
    "no": 0,
    "complianceStandard": "CIS AWS 1.2.0"
  },
  {
    "id": "5f20fb0bbb4d0700013096cb",
    "cloudName": "AWS",
    "control": "Ensure VPC flow logging is enabled in all VPCs (Scored)",
    "controlHeading": "Logging",
    "siNo": 2.9,
    "checkGroup": "VPC Flow Logs Enabled",
    "yes": 2,
    "no": 0,
    "complianceStandard": "CIS AWS 1.2.0"
  },
  {
    "id": "5f20fb0bbb4d0700013096da",
    "cloudName": "AWS",
    "control": "Ensure no security groups allow ingress from 0.0.0.0/0 to port 22 (Scored)",
    "controlHeading": "Networking",
    "siNo": 4.1,
    "checkGroup": "Open SSH",
    "yes": 2,
    "no": 0,
    "complianceStandard": "CIS AWS 1.2.0"
  }
]

the table should be grouped by "controlHeading" key.
```

But this is what I am getting in the table:
[image]

As you can see in the screenshot the group `logging` is being repeated but expected output was two row groups with title `logging` & `Networking`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Same issue. Please let me know if you found a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you an answer.
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/#grouping(enterprise)

1. Enable the enterprise features of ag-grid. Install the additional package:

   npm install --save ag-grid-enterprise

   `import 'ag-grid-enterprise';`
2. Add these to GRID_OPTIONS

   ```
   autoGroupColumnDef: {
     headerName: "Control Heading",
     field: "controlHeading",
     cellRenderer:'agGroupCellRenderer',
   },
   groupSelectsChildren: true
   ```

Comment: Ok, then can you the options I suggest and try again?

Comment: yeah, I tried with your options, still no luck. The groups somehow get nested in sublevels too.

Comment: I suspect could server-side row model be an issue here?

Comment: No, the data seems to be good. I tried with it on plunker(javascript, not react) and it worked well.
https://plnkr.co/edit/gx94LssFBs1VxGd5?preview

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the server-side row model.

When using SSRM your server is responsible to feed the grid already processed rows.
This includes filtering, sorting, grouping etc...

You have to perform grouping on your server and send back to the grid.

You can find examples under the Server-Side Data section on the ag-grid documentation page.